# Apache/PHP/Raspbian not displaying webpages correctly

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi, debian

Raspberry Pi - Debian Stretch
Apache 2.4.25
PHP 7
MyPHPAdmin
All HTTP is forwarded to HTTPS

MyPHPAdmin and PHPInfo are not displaying correctly.  Please see images.  Not sure what I did.  I was looking through Google on how to secure Apache long story short. I screwed up.  How to resolve.  Images should help explain my issue.

I am unsure of what is not working.  Color is gone and formatting from PHPInfo, and myphpadmin doesnt even show the log in box.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you check page's source code to see if is there something wrong. also please note, your page may be served on https but page might still trying to get sources from http, in this case browser will not allow this. if you're using chrome you can see errors in your inspector.

Comment: I will check the chrome error logs but as for the source code.. the myphpadmin was freshly installed. The PHP info() has nothing in it other than PHP info().